# Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 experienced an internal error

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

I am experiencing the following error - **nautilus crashed with SIGSEGV**

[image]

Comment: There is no screenshot

Comment: @It'sWillem Can you check now?

Comment: In my experience, unless things like the UI start freaking out, you can safely ignore this.

Comment: But my desktop icons have disappeared, and the file explorer stays open only for two seconds.

Comment: I just used the Unity Tweak Tool to restore the General settings. And the problem solved :D

Comment: What's the question?